# HHVM: no version information available (required by /usr/bin/hhvm)

Tags: php, centos, hhvm

I tried to install HHVM on my CentOS 6.7 server: http://hhvm.com/
"Yum install hhvm" worked fine. After starting the service it gives the following output:

```
/usr/local/lib/libz.so.1: no version information available (required by /usr/bin/hhvm)
```

Do someone know how to solve this issue?